# Probability Distribution of No. of Heads (H) when a Fair Coin is flipped 10 times (a Blitzstein and Hwang problem)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am solving Prob. 24 in Chapter - Random Variables and their distribution by Blitzstein and Hwang.
Problem:

> Let X be the number of Heads in 10 fair coin tosses.
>
> (a) Find the conditional PMF of X, given that the first two tosses both land Heads.
>
> (b) Find the conditional PMF of X, given that at least two tosses land Heads.

[Prob. 24, Random Variables and their distribution - Blitzstein and Hwang](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042794/prob-24-random-variables-and-their-distribution-blitzstein-and-hwang) has already provided a solution but I have some doubts w.r.t. the solution.

@Quasar has provided solution to (a) as:
(a) Let Z be the number of heads in the first two tosses.

$$P(X=k|Z=2)=\binom{10−2}{k−2}\frac{1}{2}^{k−2} \frac{1}{2}^{10−k}$$

But the way I'm doing, I'm getting something different:

E: be the event that first two tosses are H

$$P(E) = \frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Desired probability is:

$$P(X=x|E) = \frac{P(X=x , \space E)}{P(E)}$$

And $P(X=x , \space E)$ is $P($No. of H in 10 flips are x **and** first two flips are H$)$. Since first two are H, so we consider remaining $x-2$  H in remaining $10-2$ flips. So,

$$P(X=x , \space E) = \binom{10-2}{x-2}(\frac{1}{2})^{x-2}(\frac{1}{2})^{10-x}$$

So, finally,
$$P(X=x|E) = \frac{\binom{10-2}{x-2}(\frac{1}{2})^{x-2}(\frac{1}{2})^{10-x}}{\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$=\binom{10-2}{x-2}(\frac{1}{2})^{6}$$

**Question:** Why is he not dividing by 1/4 or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your $P(X=x, E)$ computation is actually the computation of $P(X=x|E)$. In your phrasing you say "Since first two are H, so we consider remaining $x−2$ H in remaining $10−2$ flips." The way you phrase this is saying that the first two are *given* to be H, and you have really calculated the conditional probability (correctly). Therefore no need to divide by $\tfrac14$.

P.S. good job on nicely detailed and formatted first post.

Comment: Thank you @Alborz for prompt reply! I need more clarity. But, then what would $P(X=x, E)$ be then?